# graylog-server not binding on port 12900

Tags: graylog

I have a situation here where graylog-server does not bind to port 12900 no matter what I do. I have used github.com/graylog2/graylog-ansible-role to install the rpms for graylog-server-1.1.6-1.noarch, elasticsearch-1.6.2-1.noarch, mongodb-org-server-2.6.10-1.x86_64, nginx-1.8.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 on two CentOS 7 VMs. graylog-server starts, logs no errors in /var/log/graylog/server.log but fails to bind to port 12900.

```
[root@doru2 deploy]# ps -eaf | grep graylog-server
graylog   26140  26137  7 19:01 ?        00:02:50 java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:NewRatio=1 -server -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -jar -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///etc/graylog/server/log4j.xml -Djava.library.path=/usr/share/graylog-server/lib/sigar /usr/share/graylog-server/graylog.jar server -f /etc/graylog/server/server.conf -np

[root@doru2 deploy]# netstat -tunelp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      991        100234     25747/mongod        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          16996      820/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          22667      1563/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          22086      1504/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          24601      1994/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          16999      820/rpcbind         
tcp6       0      0 10.1.10.134:9200        :::*                    LISTEN      990        53978      10878/java          
tcp6       0      0 10.1.10.134:9300        :::*                    LISTEN      990        52910      10878/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          22088      1504/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          24602      1994/master         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           0          16934      820/rpcbind         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           0          17863      813/chronyd         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           0          17865      813/chronyd         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18893           0.0.0.0:*                           0          21509      1311/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53726           0.0.0.0:*                           70         18826      793/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:973             0.0.0.0:*                           0          16995      820/rpcbind         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           70         18825      793/avahi-daemon: r

[root@doru2 deploy]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eno16777736
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 9200/tcp 9300/udp 12900/tcp 9300/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

[root@doru2 deploy]# systemctl status iptables
iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

[root@doru2 deploy]# semanage port -l | grep 12900
http_port_t                    tcp      12900, 80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
```

The SElinux audit log shows no relevant exceptions.

```
[root@doru2 deploy]# grep -v -w graylog-web /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep -v -w crond_t
type=MAC_POLICY_LOAD msg=audit(1438973046.052:25205): policy loaded auid=1001 ses=2
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1438973046.052:25205): arch=c000003e syscall=1 success=yes exit=3770462 a0=4 a1=7f7f2403e010 a2=39885e a3=7ffeb5dd0760 items=0 ppid=69239 pid=69302 auid=1001 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=2 comm="load_policy" exe="/usr/sbin/load_policy" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=MAC_POLICY_LOAD msg=audit(1438973101.674:25222): policy loaded auid=1001 ses=2
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1438973101.674:25222): arch=c000003e syscall=1 success=yes exit=3770418 a0=4 a1=7f41b3048010 a2=398832 a3=7ffde8b85280 items=0 ppid=69492 pid=69562 auid=1001 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=2 comm="load_policy" exe="/usr/sbin/load_policy" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1438973169.169:25243): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='avc:  received policyload notice (seqno=2)  exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1438973169.169:25244): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='avc:  received policyload notice (seqno=3)  exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1438973169.174:25245): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg=' comm="graylog-server" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1438973169.195:25246): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg=' comm="graylog-server" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

The Graylog server log shows that it keeps registering zen multicast transport handlers even if configured to use only unicast addresses.

```
2015-08-06T18:42:36.749-07:00 INFO  [CmdLineTool] Loaded plugins: [Anonymous Usage Statistics 1.1.1 [org.graylog.plugins.usagestatistics.UsageStatsPlugin]]
2015-08-06T18:42:36.879-07:00 INFO  [CmdLineTool] Running with JVM arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx1g -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///etc/graylog/server/log4j.xml -Djava.library.path=/usr/share/graylog-server/lib/sigar
2015-08-06T18:42:40.871-07:00 INFO  [InputBufferImpl] Message journal is enabled.
2015-08-06T18:42:41.234-07:00 INFO  [LogManager] Loading log 'messagejournal-0'
2015-08-06T18:42:41.304-07:00 INFO  [KafkaJournal] Initialized Kafka based journal at /var/lib/graylog-server/journal
2015-08-06T18:42:41.316-07:00 INFO  [InputBufferImpl] Initialized InputBufferImpl with ring size <65536> and wait strategy <BlockingWaitStrategy>, running 2 parallel message handlers.
2015-08-06T18:42:41.486-07:00 INFO  [NodeId] Node ID: 22261716-e535-47eb-a02b-395b2f2983ee
2015-08-06T18:42:41.713-07:00 INFO  [node] [doru2] version[1.6.2], pid[17622], build[6220391/2015-07-29T09:24:47Z]
2015-08-06T18:42:41.713-07:00 INFO  [node] [doru2] initializing ...
2015-08-06T18:42:41.782-07:00 INFO  [plugins] [doru2] loaded [graylog2-monitor], sites []
2015-08-06T18:42:43.988-07:00 WARN  [transport] [doru2] Registered two transport handlers for action internal:discovery/zen/multicast, handlers: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@171228a4, org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@292a32d1
2015-08-06T18:42:44.727-07:00 WARN  [transport] [doru2] Registered two transport handlers for action internal:discovery/zen/multicast, handlers: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@22e2821f, org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@171228a4
2015-08-06T18:42:44.729-07:00 WARN  [transport] [doru2] Registered two transport handlers for action internal:discovery/zen/multicast, handlers: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@7ff210cf, org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@22e2821f
2015-08-06T18:42:44.731-07:00 WARN  [transport] [doru2] Registered two transport handlers for action internal:discovery/zen/multicast, handlers: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@6d2dc7a8, org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@7ff210cf
2015-08-06T18:42:44.743-07:00 WARN  [transport] [doru2] Registered two transport handlers for action internal:discovery/zen/multicast, handlers: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@4099f1f0, org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@6d2dc7a8
2015-08-06T18:42:44.744-07:00 WARN  [transport] [doru2] Registered two transport handlers for action internal:discovery/zen/multicast, handlers: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@3adae4b2, org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$MulticastPingResponseRequestHandler@4099f1f0
```

2300 warnings were logged in a 20 minutes time span. The essence of /etc/graylog/server/server.conf is:

```
[root@doru2 deploy]# grep -v ^\# /etc/graylog/server/server.conf | sort -u
allow_highlighting = false
allow_leading_wildcard_searches = false
dead_letters_enabled = false
elasticsearch_analyzer = standard
elasticsearch_cluster_discovery_timeout = 5000
elasticsearch_cluster_name = graylog-cluster
elasticsearch_config_file = /etc/graylog/server/elasticsearch.yml
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_multicast_enabled = False
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = ['10.1.10.133:9300', '10.1.10.134:9300']
elasticsearch_http_enabled = false
elasticsearch_index_prefix = graylog2
elasticsearch_max_docs_per_index = 20000000
elasticsearch_max_number_of_indices = 20
elasticsearch_network_bind_host = 
elasticsearch_network_host = 
elasticsearch_network_publish_host = 
elasticsearch_node_data = false
elasticsearch_node_master = false
elasticsearch_node_name = doru2
elasticsearch_replicas = 0
elasticsearch_shards = 4
elasticsearch_transport_tcp_port = 9300
is_master = false
lb_recognition_period_seconds = 3
message_journal_dir = /var/lib/graylog-server/journal
message_journal_enabled = true
message_journal_max_age = 12h
message_journal_max_size = 5gb
mongodb_max_connections = 100
mongodb_password = 
mongodb_replica_set = localhost:27017
mongodb_threads_allowed_to_block_multiplier = 5
mongodb_uri = mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/graylog
mongodb_useauth = false
mongodb_user = 
node_id_file = /etc/graylog/server/node-id
output_batch_size = 25
outputbuffer_processors = 3
output_flush_interval = 1
password_secret = 2jueVqZpwLLjaWxV
plugin_dir = /usr/share/graylog-server/plugin
processbuffer_processors = 5
processor_wait_strategy = blocking
rest_enable_cors = true
rest_enable_gzip = true
rest_listen_uri = http://127.0.0.1:12900/
rest_transport_uri = http://127.0.0.1:12900/
retention_strategy = delete
root_email = 
root_password_sha2 = 8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
root_timezone = UTC
root_username = admin
rotation_strategy = count
stream_processing_max_faults = 3
stream_processing_timeout = 2000
telemetry_enabled = false
transport_email_auth_password = 
transport_email_auth_username = 
transport_email_enabled = false
transport_email_from_email = 
transport_email_hostname = 
transport_email_port = 587
transport_email_subject_prefix = [graylog]
transport_email_use_auth = true
transport_email_use_ssl = true
transport_email_use_tls = true
transport_email_web_interface_url =
```

The only error I see is in /var/log/messages

```
Aug  7 12:32:59 localhost systemd: Started Graylog server.
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:179)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:72)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2865)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printString(Formatter.java:2838)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2718)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.internal.Errors.format(Errors.java:474)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.CreationException.getMessage(CreationException.java:55)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printString(Formatter.java:2838)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2718)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2792)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.format(Errors.java:556)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.addMessage(Errors.java:539)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.errorInUserCode(Errors.java:421)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.errorInProvider(Errors.java:376)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:74)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
Aug  7 12:37:20 localhost graylog-server: at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
```

The VM I am using has 4GB of RAM and the JVM is configured to use 1G. I wonder if the out-of-memory error is a result of starting tons of multicast transport handlers. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if SELinux is blocking the port.

Comment: Thanks, but It does not look like that. I have updated the post to include SElinux details.

Answer (score 1):

I traced this back to the elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts value in /etc/graylog/server/server.conf. This is a Java property file so values need to be formatted as such:

```
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = 10.1.10.134:9300
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = 10.1.10.134:9300,10.1.10.133:9300
```

Avoid YAML formats like this. The Graylog code, as in 1.1.6, does not flag improperly formatted values.

```
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = "10.1.10.134:9300"
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = [ "10.1.10.134:9300" ]
```